# Async Await ...and Tasks. What am I doing wrong

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am learning/ experimenting with the Async Await features. I have a button click event that calls this code:

```
       //first select the direcgtory in this event.  Then called the async function..to be written
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foldername = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }
       // CreateFilesParellel();
        var x = CreateAsync();
```

Here is what the function CreateAsync looks like: Mode details go here

```
    async Task<int> CreateAsync()
    {
        string fileType;
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        //get the files in the existing directory.
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(foldername);

        fileType = Path.GetExtension(files[0]);
        var filepath = Path.GetFullPath(files[0]);
        string d = Path.GetDirectoryName(files[0]);
        var ss = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[0]);
        var progress = new Progress<string>();
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {

            Action act = () =>
            {
                File.Copy(files[0], d + "\\" + ss + i.ToString() + fileType);
            };

           //await File.Copy(files[0], d + "\\" + ss + i.ToString() + fileType);
            Task t = new Task(act);
            tasks.Add(t);
           // t.Start();
            progress.ProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
            {

                textBox1.Text = System.Environment.NewLine;
                textBox1.Text = "Creating file =  " + e;

            };
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);



        sw.Stop();
        string ExecutionTimeTaken = string.Format("Minutes :{0}\nSeconds :{1}\n Mili seconds :{2}", sw.Elapsed.Minutes, sw.Elapsed.Seconds, sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

        MessageBox.Show(ExecutionTimeTaken);
        return 0;


    }
```

So here is the question.   When I run this code nothing happens. Meaning files are not getting created.  What am I doing wrong?  Or what am I missing?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957 , please go through this document. I found it particularly useful.

Answer (score 6):

You never start your `Task`.

In general, you should use `Task.Run`, not `new Task`, to create (already running) tasks.

```
// Replace:
// Task t = new Task(act);
// tasks.Add(t);

// With:
tasks.Add(Task.Run(act));
```

That being said, this is likely not a good candidate for this type of parallelism (creating multiple tasks).  Since you're doing pure disk IO, you'll likely receive a bottleneck on the drive itself.

You'd likely be better off leaving this routine as a non-async, serial routine, and just wrapping it in a single `Task.Run` at your call site:

```
   //first select the direcgtory in this event.  Then called the async function..to be written
    if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foldername = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    }

    int result = await Task.Run(CreateFiles);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the input.  I was trying to understand the difference between Parallel.Foreach and the await async.  I do realize because of the disc I/o this is not a good candidate for tasks. I just could think of anything cleverer

Comment: @Waddaulookingat In general, pure disk I/O will never parallelize (it'll typically run slower in parallel, since it forces the platter to jump too frequently)